# How to find Frequency of word in arrayList of type extended class

Tags: java

This a Restaurant Class which stores different colours of Receipts. I'm trying to get the Frequency of each Receipt colour using `Collections.Frequency`

*note* the use of `Collections.Frequency` is a must.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Resturant> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
     list1.add(new Drive_Through(4, 20, 2));
     list1.add(new Walk_in(5, 15, 10, 10));
     list1.add(new Drive_Through(3, 5, 5));
     list1.add(new Walk_in(1, 3, 10,20));
     
     
    System.out.println("\n\n\n----Number of Green Recipet----\n"+Collections.frequency(list1, "Green"));
```

List contents:

`Receipt No.: 1, Date/Time: 27/08/20, Recipt Colour: Green, Total items: 3, Total Tax: 0.1, Total Payment: 2.64, Total Discount: 0.6600000000000001`

`Receipt No.: 3, Date/Time: 27/08/20, Recipt Colour: White, Total items: 5, Total Tax: 0.05, Total Payment: 5.25`

`Receipt No.: 4, Date/Time: 27/08/20, Recipt Colour: White, Total items: 20, Total Tax: 0.02, Total Payment: 20.4`

`Receipt No.: 5, Date/Time: 27/08/20, Recipt Colour: Green, Total items: 15, Total Tax: 0.1, Total Payment: 14.85, Total Discount: 1.6500000000000001]`

Comment: @Michael sorry i'm new let me edit.

Comment: @Michael Check the edit.

Comment: "*the use of Collections.Frequency is must*" It is not possible. An instance of `Drive_Through` is not equal to the String `"Green`". They are different classes, and are not equal by definition.

Comment: @Michael any idea? what will solve my problem.

Comment: Remove the illogical constraint of having to use `Collections.Frequency` is step 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Collections.frequency` checks equality of the given object to all the elements of collection, this could be implemented by overriding `equals` method to compare only one property (`color` in the given case):

```java
class Receipt {
    // properties, constructor(s), getters, setters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (null == o) {
            return false;
        }
        
        Color otherColor = null;
        if (o instanceof Color) {
            otherColor = (Color) o;
        } else if (o instanceof Receipt) {
            otherColor = ((Receipt) o).getColor();
        }
        return null != this.color && this.color.equals(otherColor);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.color.hashCode;
    }
}


// using Collections.frequency
List<Receipt> receipts = prepareReceipts();
int greenCount = Collections.frequency(receipts, Color.GREEN);
```

This can be used only as a "hardcoded" solution for the required case.

If the frequency needs to be calculated by another property or properties, it's better to implement a decorators/set of decorators using the suggested approach.